# tls.Dial returns "too many colons in address"

Tags: go

I am trying to loop through an array of addresses, and check their tls cert status. I pieced together a program from various examples that do other things.

My first step in processing is

```
conn, err := tls.Dial("tcp", url, nil)
```

where 'url' is passed in from the array (I do import `crypto/tls`). Before I go on to pulling the cert, I check for errors:

```
if err != nil { 
    log.Printf("Unable to get %q - %s\n", url, err)
    return
}
```

Here is a snippet of the array (with only test addresses for now):

```
var urls = []string{
    "https://google.com:443",
    "https://expired.badssl.com:443",
    "[https://wrong.host.badssl.com]:443",
    "[https://self-signed.badssl.com]:443"
}
```

The first 2 return `too many colons in address`
I found a suggestion to fix that using the brackets. The next 2 addresses, with the brackets, return `no such host`

Where is my error?

Comment: Why the downvotes? How can I improve?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It should be domain name, IPv4 or IPv6 address with port only, not URL.

```
conn, err := tls.Dial("tcp", "mail.google.com:443", &tls.Config{
    RootCAs: roots,
})
```